# dataSourceChanged event not triggered

Tags: syncfusion, react-data-grid

I pulled the example [repo](https://github.com/SyncfusionExamples/handling-crud-actions-using-fetch-api-and-react-grid-events/blob/master/after/) to [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-data-grid-datasourcechanged-not-firing-0mekl) and trying to trigger `dataSourceChanged` event pushing ui buttons like "Update", "Add" and logging the `state` variable to the console (lines 41-42 of App.tsx):

```
  function dataSourceChanged(state: any) {
    console.log(state); //should log to the console
```

any idea why it's not firing when im pushing new rows to the grid or updating existing ones? Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Syncfusion support answered me directly on this one. I had to change getOrders function

```
export function getOrders() { 
  return fetch(baseUrl + "/orders") 
    .then((res) => res.json()) 
    .then((data) => { 
      return { 
        count: data.length, 
        result: data 
      }; 
    }); 
}
```